# Is there a way to start debugger on exception or test failure in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js

What I am looking for is basically `nosetest --pdb --pdb-failures` from [nose testing framework](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/debug.html).

I am using mocha for testing. What I'd like to do is to run tests like

`mocha --break-on-exception --break-on-failure` that would stop executing tests once encountering exception or assertion failure, would start [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) for me and would allow me to introspect runninng code.

Is this possible anywhere in node.js world, with any library or test framework?

Comment: you can do `mocha debug` and then from command line debugger type `breakOnExeption`. Note that there are lots of internal try/catch excheptions, for example each module require without explicit '.js' extension generates ENOENT exception. I suggest to turn on `breakOnExeption` after all your modules are loaded

Answer (score 5):

add this line to your test:

```
if (global.v8debug)
   global.v8debug.Debug.setBreakOnException()
```

start with `mocha --debug-brk`, connect node-inspector, continue and wait for exception

Comment: This is exactly what I don't want to do; I want to break on exception/failure automatically, without modifying test code.

Comment: Have you found another solution?

Comment: i'm trying to do this from `node debug myapp.js` but it seems that `global.v8debug` is not defined...